# KNO3 as reverse hybrid oxidizer?

Tags: rockets, propulsion

Say I want to make a reverse hybrid rocket motor, that runs on a gaseous/liquid fuel which is passed by a solid oxidizer. Would KNO3 make a good oxidizer?  Or does this concept not work with Liquid fuels?

Comment: KNO3 makes a lousy oxidizer generally, producing moderate amounts of oxygen and a plenty of KNO2 which at the KNO3 decomposition temperature is a thick, sticky liquid gunking up any nozzless, sticking and solidifying into a thick crust in contact with everything not burning hot. It's  a general nuisance. Consider KMnO4 maybe.

Answer (score 2):

In theory this should work, You may run into problems regarding keeping the potassium nitrate solid as it may tend to fall apart. Finding a binder that would keep the potassium nitrate solid but not turn itself into a solid fuel may be a challenge. You could also maybe just compact the potassium nitrate onto itself to hold its shape. Either way it will be a challenge but again in theory this should work.